# Is Shortest Hamiltonian path NP-hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, np, np-complete, np-hard

Hamiltonian Path is a path that connects all nodes without repeat and it is an NP-complete problem.

1. Is the Shortest Hamiltonian Path (SHP) NP-hard?
2. What is the difference between travelling salesman problem with SHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the SHP problem is the Hamiltonian problem on the edge weighted graph. It is NP-hard because it is at least as hard as the Hamiltonian problem. Assume you have an algorithm to solve the SHP problem, then you apply the algorithm on a weighted graph with all edge weights are 1, it will solve the Hamiltonian problem with the same time complexity.

[TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) requires to return to the original vertex and you can visit each vertex more one once. SHP asks for the path which visits every vertex exactly once.